# eGalaxy Touchscreen On Jessie

Tags: raspbian-jessie

Ok, I'm new to StackExchange but I have the same Problem others seem to have, too.
I picked up the answers I found so far. What I see on my system is, that I have TWO eGalaxy devices. They are listed as follows:

```
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0eef Product=0001 Version=0112
N: Name="eGalax Inc. Touch"
P: Phys=usb-3f980000.usb-1.5/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/0003:0EEF:0001.0004/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 js0 event0
B: PROP=0
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=30000 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=3
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0eef Product=0001 Version=0112
N: Name="eGalax Inc. Touch"
P: Phys=usb-3f980000.usb-1.5/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/0003:0EEF:0001.0004/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event1
B: PROP=0
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=401 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=3
B: MSC=10
```

When I do evtest input0 does nothing at all, input1 reacts as it should, as far as I can see with evtest.
The only differences I see is in "Handler" the js0 for input0, also "Key"=3000 ... in input0 as opposed to "Key"=401 ... in input1.
Is there a way to disable input0? I did a complete fresh install of the latest Rasbian Jessie versin (2017-06-21), no additional Drivers.

Thanks Karl

Comment: Drivers in /sys often have a "bind" and an "unbind" entry that you can use to remove endpoints (not sure in this specific case).  Does "echo input0 > .../input" do anything?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When I look into /sys, I see as the closest to what you say this:

Comment: /sys/class/Input:
[very Long Name]input0
[very Long Name]event0
Can I just delete them?

Answer (score 0):

I am having this problem with Jessie to but I am new to this so I don't know if this helps.
I have the eGalax touch screen (Lilliput) working with the Wheezy operating system. When I looked at devices (as above) for wheezy I got the two input references (as I do with Jessie) but this works perfectly with Wheezy. 
I suspect the second is possibly a milti touch input.
Unfortunately I can't offer any solution but it might not be the second input reference.
John.